# Send a Private Message on Facebook when name is not in available list

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I want to send a private message on Facebook to someone who is my friend. However, when I select that option their name does not come up in the list of names to chose from. How can I send them a private message?

Comment: Is it possible they've blocked you?

Answer (score 1):

If that person is your friend, name should be come in the list. You can refresh the page or check with other browsers.

Other way is go to that person's profile. Click on `Message` tab and send the message. If person is in your friend list, message will go in Inbox otherwise it will go in "Other" folder in the inbox.